# Differences between structs

Tags: c, struct, malloc

```
typedef struct student{        
char *fName;        
char *lName;        
int pid;
}student;

vs

typedef struct student{        
char fName;        
char lName;        
int pid;
}student;
```

What would be the difference in usage of these two structs? Like why would I use one over the other?

Comment: The second one is wrong!

Comment: And what's it got to do with malloc? 
To be more helpful - the first one can point to a string for the names, but the second only hold a single character per name. Not too useful :)

Comment: `char` is just a single character. `char *` is a pointer to a character, which is typically going to be a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: You would use the second one if you only character about the student's initials, not their whole names.

Comment: did you mean something like `char fName[20]` for the second case? Otherwise it rarely makes sense.

Comment: If all your students are named "F J", "B H", and "R P", then the second one is fine. But as soon as you add a John or a Smith you run out of room.

Answer (score 4):

The first struct holds a pointer to a character of `fName` and `lName`, which are *typically* stored as a character array (can be used to represent a single character).

The second one simply stores one `char`, meaning you couldn't enter the students full name

Comment: While mostly correct, I'm going to be a little pedantic to point out that the first struct's `fName` and `lName` are not necessarily pointing to arrays as they can point to just a single character each.  They CAN (and most likely do based on context) point to character arrays.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. `char fname` can store only one character while `char *fname` is a pointer that can point to a `string` not alone a single `character`.

So, if you want to store the whole name then you should use first type of structure and if you want to store just the initials of person's full name then you should go with second structure.

Note: `char *fname` can only store a string after memory allocation using `malloc()` or `calloc()`